# How can I narrow down the gaps?

Tags: cv, resume

[image: Change the size of block]

[image: latex]

I am writing my curriculum vitae, but I have one question.

In the first image, there are spaces between different sections.

(Between contact and phone, between education and Seoul~~,....)

Thus, I want to narrow down these gaps.

How can I solve this problem??

(I tried to modify the code.... code is in the second image....)

Comment: Code in an image is not very helpful because we can't copy it and run it on our own computers to find the error.  Please add a complete minimal working example to your question. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Next time, please don't open a new question. Instead, you can edit your existing question to update it. (There is an 'edit' link at the bottom left of your post.) I've started a vote to close this as a duplicate. (Normally, the newer question would be the duplicate but since you've added code there, it seemed easier this way.)